# To implement cURL in my application, will my clients have to download it as well?

Tags: curl

I installed `cURL` using their installation executable, if I want to implement this feature in my software will users of my software also have to install `cURL`? I'm developing it in unmanaged `C++.`

Comment: NO need to install it on user's system..

Answer (score 0):

No, need to install it on user system..

Curl is free and open software that compiles and runs under a wide variety of operating systems. Curl exists thanks to efforts from many contributors.

curl is a command line tool for transferring data with URL syntax, supporting `DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, Gopher, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMTP, SMTPS, Telnet and TFTP`. curl supports SSL certificates, `HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP uploading, HTTP form based upload, proxies, cookies, user+password authentication (Basic, Digest, NTLM, Negotiate, kerberos...)`, file transfer resume, proxy tunneling and a busload of other useful tricks.

cURL is a computer software project providing a library and command-line tool for transferring data using various protocols. The cURL project produces two products, libcurl and cURL.

Answer (score 0):

If the application work only with curl, you need to package the same along with your application, install the same if it's not already available on the system. Else you can give it as an optional during the installation.